# Operation on languages results in CFL

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, regular-languages

> For every two languages $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ over the alphabet $\{ a,b,c,d \}$, we define the language
>   $$L_{1} \operatorname{op} L_{2} = \{ \alpha\beta \mid \text{$\alpha \in L_{1}$ and $\beta \in L_{2}$ and $|\alpha| \le |\beta|$}\}.$$
>
> 1) If $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ are CFL then is $L_{1} \operatorname{op} L_{2}$ always CFL?
>
> 2) if $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ are regular languages then is $L_{1} \operatorname{op} L_{2}$ always CFL?

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus for 1) As a counterexample the intersection of 2 CFL is not CFL . 2) I think it is not true ,however I can't think of counterexample

Comment: I'm not sure why the counterexample is relevant - here we are interested in a different operation.

Comment: As it happens, the answer to 1 is "false" and to 2 is "true".

Comment: You are misunderstanding the question. You are *given* a specific operations, and the question asks what happens when you apply this operation to two context-free or regular languages.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Can you provide some hints or explanation why ?

Comment: It seems that up to now you have misunderstood the question. Given that, I suggest that you now try to solve it on your own for a few days.